# Subsetting JSON data

Tags: json, f#, f#-data

Please consider this dataset:

```
type Deck = JsonProvider<"...">
let dt = Deck.GetSamples()

dt

[{"collectible":true,"health":4,"artist":"Zoltan Boros","type":"MINION","cost":1,"attack":2},
{"collectible":true,"health":8,"artist":"James Ryman","type":"MINION","cost":8,"attack":8},
{"collectible":true,"health":3,"artist":"Warren Mahy", "type":"LAND","cost":2,"attack":2}]
```

I am trying to build a function capable of extracting certain info from it and, eventually, store them in a smaller dataset. It should, given a list-like dataset `deck`, consider only the cards that for the `key`s equal to given `value`s.

```
let rec filter deck key value =
    let rec aux l1 l2 l3 =
        match l1 with
        [] -> []
        | x::xs when x.l2 = l3 -> x::(aux xs key value)
    aux deck key value
```

For example,

```
filter dt type minion
```

should subset the deck in a smaller one with only the first and second card. I think I did few steps forward in getting the concept, but still it does not work, throwing an error of kind

```
FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to
this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to 
constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
```

How should I define the type of `key`? I tried with `key : string` and `key : string list`, without succeed.

Comment: Why? I don't think you can interpret code as a string without either quotation marks of the `?` operator, but regardless, it defies the point of having a type provider in the first place. What's wrong with using a filter function, like `fun (c : Deck.Root) -> c.Type = "MINION"`?

Comment: @Vandroiy, nothing wrong in a filter function. I was simply not aware of them. Thank you for showing it to me.

Comment: @Worice In any language it helps to be familiar with its collections and the functions that operate on them (maybe more so in functional languages). This is a nice overview: [Collections & Functions](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/).

Comment: @s952163 you are totally right. I admit that I have not been able to dedicate to every part of collections and relative functions the time they deserve. I am going to fill the gap as soon as possible. Thank you for the reference, I love that website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to re-implement `filter`?

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
#endif

open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let jsonFile = @"C:\tmp\test.json"

type Json = JsonProvider<jsonFile>
let deck = Json.Load(jsonFile)

deck |> Seq.filter (fun c -> c.Type = "MINION")
```

Gives me:

> val it : seq.Root> =   seq
>       [{   "collectible": true,   "health": 4,   "artist": "Zoltan Boros",   "type": "MINION",   "cost": 1,   "attack": 2 };
>        {   "collectible": true,   "health": 8,   "artist": "James Ryman",   "type": "MINION",   "cost": 8,   "attack": 8 }]

Comment: It works, thank you. Unfortunately, I fail to get a complete grasp on how it works. You just passed to Seq.filter a condition to test, and that is ok. I am not sure I get `c.`. Is it the the parameter that, in this case, will be `deck`?

Comment: @Worice it's black magiks. ;-) `c` represents the card in the deck (you could write `x` or `card`). Collections functions like `map`, `filter`, etc. will operate on each individual element of the deck, which is a card in this case so you can read it as give me each card when its Type is "MINION".

Comment: @Worice you can always drop by the [F# Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f/)

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thank you for your patience, I am training hard to become a wizard :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to annotate the type of l1.

setting `l1: something list` should be what you want.

Key doesn't help as type inference is top to bottom and `x.l2` is before `aux` is called with `key` as an argument

Comment: Thank you for your answer John.